# How can I capture screen output to a named file on a command by command bases?

Tags: io-redirection

I am running commands remotely `stuff`ing them into `screen` commands via SSH. Rather than type directly into the terminal displayed, I use remote SSH commands which are run by clicking a button in a GUI. I use the `screen` command because it allows me to see the terminal without having to type directly in it.

For every command executed I want the screen output to be saved to a specified file, in addition to being displayed on the terminal. Not all commands are necessarily executed by `stuff`ing into the remote screen. The commands can be saved into a script which is uploaded to the remote computer and the `screen` `stuff` command used to run it.

How do I setup the command to save to a named file in addition to displaying the output as normal. Use of `screen` is a convenience but I am looking for a method which can work without `screen/tmux` being involved.

Comment: Have you looked at the `script` command?  Or if you want a more integrated solution, maybe https://asciinema.org/ ?

Comment: despite the gui, do you do something like `ssh $host screen`? If it's this simple, you could just `tee` the output into a file

Comment: @Hachi Is it this simple? I looked up `tee` and it looks like it will do what I want. I thought I asked this kind of question before and didn't get an answer. I will try it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Stephen Harris said, `script` command will write to a file but it will overwrite its contents each time you use it. Use `script -a` to append to it.

`script` will save everything in your terminal to a file.